Finding a projection of a point onto a line that does not pass through origin
In Ivan Savov's "No Bullshit Guide to Linear Algebra" (page 250, Chapter 4.2) he defines projection of an arbitrary vector $\vec{u}$ onto a line
$$\Pi_l(\vec{u}) = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}}{||\vec{v}||^2} \vec{v}$$
where $l$ passes through origin and $\vec{v}$ is its direction vector
he then proceeds to ask a student to solve a problem (page 255)
"Consider the point $p=(10,10,10)$ and a line $l=\{(3,0,5)+t(1,-2,0): t \in \mathbb{R}\}$, find (a) $\Pi_l(p)$ (b) d(p, l)"
I wonder how one would approach this problem with the prep the author gave. Intuitively you would try and translate the line so that it passes through origin, which would also require translating the point $p$. If you deduct (3,0,5) from both the line's intercept and then $p$ and compute projection, you will get an incorrect answer. The right way to go about this would be to make a vector out of $p$, whose origin goes from line's intercept. i.e. (10, 10, 10) - (3, 0, 5). Then find projection of that onto the line. I believe this would give partially correct answer, you would need to shift this projection then back to the line by adding (3, 0, 5)?
As for distance from line to $p$, performing translations actually yields the right answer. First translation is to make p the new origin. Which means the new intercept would be (3, 0, 5) - (10, 10, 10). He also gives in the book an equation for how to find distance between origin and a line that does not pass through origin. So this works out well.
My question is the following: just from the knowledge presented in this question and some common / basic properties of vectors, how would one be expected to find solutions to these questions. Mostly interested in finding projection of p onto l.

You have the right idea. Move the origin, do the projection, then move the origin back.

yup, that worked. i was missing that last shifting back from origin to where the line is. thanks!
